# MySQL subquery from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with table xxx_facileforms_forms, xxx_facileforms_records and xxx_facileforms_subrecords.

Column headers for xxx_facileforms_subrecords:

```
id | record | element | title | neame | type | value
```

As far as filtering records with element = '101' ..query returns proper records, but when i add subquery to filete aditional element = '4871' from same table - 0 records returned.

```
SELECT
F.id AS form_id,
R.id AS record_id,
PV.value AS prim_val,
COUNT(PV.value) AS count
FROM
xxx_facileforms_forms AS F
INNER JOIN xxx_facileforms_records AS R ON F.id = R.form
INNER JOIN xxx_facileforms_subrecords AS PV ON R.id = PV.record AND PV.element = '101'
WHERE R.id IN (SELECT record FROM xxx_facileforms_records WHERE record = R.id AND element = '4871')
GROUP BY PV.value
```

Does this looks right?

Thank You!

**EDIT**

Thank you for support and ideas! Yes, I left lot of un guessing. Sorry. Some input/output table data might help make it more clear.

```
_facileforms_form:
id | formname
---+---------
1  | myform

_facileforms_records:
id  | form | submitted
----+------+--------------------
163 | 1    | 2014-06-12 14:18:00
164 | 1    | 2014-06-12 14:19:00
165 | 1    | 2014-06-12 14:20:00

_facileforms_subrecords:
id   | record | element | title  | name|type   | value
-----+--------+---------+--------+-------------+--------
5821 | 163    | 101     | ticket | radio group | flight
5822 | 163    | 4871    | status | select list | canceled
5823 | 164    | 101     | ticket | radio group | flight
5824 | 165    | 101     | ticket | radio group | flight
5825 | 165    | 4871    | status | select list | canceled
```

---

Successful query result:

```
form_id | record_id | prim_val |  count
1       | 163       | flight   | 2
```

So i have to return value data (& sum those records) from those records where _subrecord element - 4871 is present (in this case 163 and 165).

And again Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't look quite right. There's a predicate "**`R.id IN (subquery)`**" but that subquery itself has a reference to **`R.id`**; it's a correlated subquery. Looks like something is doubled up there. (We're assuming here that **`id`** is a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key in each table.)

The subquery references an identifier `element`... the only other reference we see to that identifier is from the `_subrecords` table (we don't see any reference to that column in `_records` table... if there's no `element` column in `_records`, then that's a reference to the `element` column in `PV`, and that predicate in the subquery will never be true at the same time the `PV.element='101'` predicate is true.

Kudos for qualifying the column references with a table alias, that makes the query (and the EXPLAIN output) much easier to read; the reader doesn't need to go digging around in the table definitions to figure out which table does and doesn't contain which columns. But please take that pattern to the next step, and qualify **all** column references in the query, **including** column references in the subqueries.

Since the reference to `element` isn't qualified, we're left to guess whether the `_records` table contains a column named `element`.

---

If the goal is to return only the rows from `R` with `element='4871'`, we could just do...

```
WHERE R.element='4871'
```

But, given that you've gone to the bother of using a subquery, I suspect that's not really what you want.

It's possible you're trying to return all rows from `R` for a `_form`, but only for the `_form` where there's at least one associated `_record` with **`element='4871'`**. We could get that result returned with either an **`IN (subquery)`** or an **`EXISTS (correlated_ subquery)`** predicate, or an **`anti-join`** pattern. I'd give examples of those query patterns; I could take some guesses at the specification, but I would only be guessing at what you actually want to return.

But I'm guessing that's not really what you want. I suspect that `_records` doesn't actually contain a column named `element`.

The query is already restricting the rows returned from `PV` with those that have `element='101'`.)

This is a case where some example data and the example output would help explain the actual specification; and that would be a basis for developing the required SQL.

**FOLLOWUP**

I'm just guessing... maybe what you want is something pretty simple. Maybe you want to return rows that have element value of either '101' or '4913'.

The `IN` comparison operator is a convenient of way of expressing the OR condition, that a column be equal to a value in a list:

```
SELECT F.id              AS form_id
     , R.id              AS record_id
     , PV.value          AS prim_val
     , COUNT(PV.value)   AS count
  FROM xxx_facileforms_forms F
  JOIN xxx_facileforms_records R 
    ON R.form = F.id
  JOIN xxx_facileforms_subrecords PV 
    ON PV.record = R.id
   AND PV.element IN ('101','4193')
 GROUP BY PV.value
```

NOTE: This query (like the OP query) is using a non-standard MySQL extension to GROUP BY, which allows non-aggregate expressions (e.g. bare columns) to be returned in the SELECT list.

The values returned for the non-aggregate expressions (in this case, `F.id` and `R.id`) will be a values from a row included in the "group". But because there can be multiple rows, and different values on those rows, it's not deterministic which of values will be returned. (Other databases would reject this statement, unless we wrapped those columns in an aggregate function, such as MIN() or MAX().)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

I noticed that you added information about the question into an answer... this information would better be *added* to the question as an EDIT, since it's not an *answer* to the question.  I took the liberty of copying that, and reformatting.

The example makes it much more clear what you are trying to accomplish.

I think the *easiest to understand* is to use EXISTS predicate, to check whether a row meeting some criteria "exists" or not, and exclude rows where such a row does not exist. This will use a correlated subquery of the _subrecords table, to which check for the existence of a matching row:

```
SELECT f.id              AS form_id
     , r.id              AS record_id
     , pv.value          AS prim_val
     , COUNT(pv.value)   AS count
  FROM xxx_facileforms_forms f
  JOIN xxx_facileforms_records r 
    ON r.form = f.id
  JOIN xxx_facileforms_subrecords pv
    ON pv.record = r.id
   AND pv.element = '101'
-- only include rows where there's also a related 4193 subrecord
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM xxx_facileforms_subrecords sx
                  WHERE sx.element = '4193'
                    AND sx.record = r.id
              )
--
 GROUP BY pv.value
```

(I'm thinking this is where OP was headed with the idea that a subquery was required.)

Given that there's a GROUP BY in the query, we could actually accomplish an equivalent result with a regular join operation, to a second reference to the _subrecords table.

A join operation is often more efficient than using an EXISTS predicate.

(Note that the existing `GROUP BY` clause will eliminate any "duplicates" that might otherwise be introduced by a JOIN operation, so this will return an equivalent result.)

```
SELECT f.id              AS form_id
     , r.id              AS record_id
     , pv.value          AS prim_val
     , COUNT(pv.value)   AS count
  FROM xxx_facileforms_forms f
  JOIN xxx_facileforms_records r
    ON r.form = f.id
  JOIN xxx_facileforms_subrecords pv
    ON pv.record = r.id
   AND pv.element = '101'
-- only include rows where there's also a related 4193 subrecord
  JOIN xxx_facileforms_subrecords sx
    ON sx.record = r.id
   AND sx.element = '4193'
--
 GROUP BY pv.value
```

Comment: Thank You for support and ideas! May be some input/output table data might help You-Help-Me to figure corect subquery..?

Comment: I'm not at all sure you need a subquery. I haven't seen anything in the specification that leads me to believe a subquery or inline view is required. (I suspect that you may want something very simple... such as returning rows with `element='101'` along with rows with `element='4193'`. And that doesn't require a subquery.

Comment: With the additional information in the question, we can recommend several possible queries that will return the desired result. I've updated my answer to include two alternatives: using an `EXISTS (correlated subquery)` and using a regular join operation.

Comment: Thank You! Both of them works exactly like they should! Actualy You right with EXIST i understood on spot, but if You say second (JOIN operation) is more eficient, i will use that, because in my table there are 10000 subrecords. 
Thenk You for help!!

Comment: @user2788571: a JOIN isn't always more efficient; in a lot of cases, with large sets, we find that to be the case. Performance is really going to depend on the availability of suitable indexes.I'm not sure I pointed this out... the JOIN approach can produce duplicate rows, for example, if you have more than one 4187 subrecord for a record, each subrecord row that matches will produce another row in the result set. But the `EXISTS` won't do that, it only has to find the first matching row, and it can return TRUE.

Comment: In this case i have single subrecord 4187 per record. So this query is perfect for the job. But thank You for explanation!!!

Just for curiosity, what would be the adjustment in this query to have AVG (average result) of values = 101 IF the value would contain numbers instead of text ....like 0.15 , 0.2 and 1.5 instead of flight, flight and flight?

To have result:

1 | 163 | 0.53 | 2

..and again THANK YOU for Your precious professional time!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for support and ideas! Yes i left lot of un guessing.. sorry . So may be some input/output table data might help.

**_facileforms_form:**

headers -> id | formname

1 | myform

**_facileforms_records:**

headers -> id | form | submitted

163 | 1 | 2014-06-12 14:18:00

164 | 1 | 2014-06-12 14:19:00

165 | 1 | 2014-06-12 14:20:00

**_facileforms_subrecords**

headers -> id | record | element | title | name | type | value

5821 | 163 | 101 | ticket | radio group| flight

5822 | 163 | 4871 | status | select list | canceled

5823 | 164 | 101 | ticket | radio group | flight

5824 | 165 | 101 | ticket | radio group | flight

5825 | 165 | 4871 | status | select list | canceled

---

Succesful Query result:

headers -> form_id | record_id | prim_val |  count

**1 | 163 | flight | 2**

So i have to return value data (& sum those records) from those records where _subrecord element - 4871 is present (in this case 163 and 165).

And again Thank You!

Comment: This is not an *answer* to the question. Additional information about the *question* should be added to the question itself. I've taken the liberty to copy and reformat this information into the question.